# How to point openvpn client to a specific gateway?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a Windows computer that is connected to LAN and Wireless. Each are on two different private networks. One is 192.x.x.x and the other one is on 172.x.x.x.

I am trying to configure the OpenVPN client to connect trough the LAN interface, which is on the 192.x.x.x network. The VPN connection connects to an outside VPN server trough the 192.x.x.x network. After that, I would use SSH trough the VPN to access the server on the network that the VPN server sits.

So I would like to use ssh to connect to the server behind the VPN but still be able to use other applications/web browsing trough the 172.x.x.x network.

What i see is the routing table and it's configured that there are two default routes that use the 172.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x gateways but the network Metric is set to lower for the 172.x.x.x network so the openVPN client uses the 172.x.x.x network, which is not the goal.

What I do for now:

I lower the metric of 192.x.x.x network in the routing table so that it's lower than the 172.x.x.x metric. Then I connect to the VPN server and change the metrics back, so all the other traffic gets routed trough the 172.x.x.x network but I can still use SSH trough the created VPN tunnel.

I am open to ideas and possible workarounds.

Comment: Why even two default routes?

Comment: I'm not sure. There are two 0.0.0.0 in my route table which point to two different gateways the 172.xxxx and the 192.xxxx, but have different Metrics.

Comment: Actually it seems that you just need a static (host) route to the VPN server that has the `192.x.x.x` gateway as its gateway, then you can keep the metrics of the default routes as-is.

Comment: How would i achieve that? I am a bit lost, so far i've written a powershell script that just swtiches the metrics between the wifi and ethernet adapter which works for me now..

Comment: `route add $VPN_Server_IP MASK 255.255.255.255 $192_Gateway_IP`? There's `New-NetRoute` for PowerShell as well, but it seems that you are required to enter the interface index with that. `Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress $192_Gateway_IP` would probably tell you that though.